# Postgresql: Count a value only once from multiple versions in a date range

Tags: sql, postgresql

Have a postgresql question.  I have a table with data from a simple query. Now I have the task of getting a single count for each quarterly date range. The request also ask to only count the first time it hits "Yes" and never again no matter how many times the "Yes" appears. I used the "min" and distinct to get the basic result but I am still capturing the additional "Yes" along with the column that has hit yes for the first time.  Here are examples of what I am doing and output I would like:

**Query result from schema TableA**

`select * from Table_A a where a.Filing_ID = '123'`:

```
Filing_ID | Version_Number | Filing_Date| HY | CF  | D4  |
```

---

```
123       |      1         | 1/18/2019 | Yes | Yes | No  |
123       |      2         | 2/18/2019 | Yes | Yes | No  |
123       |      3         | 4/1/2019  | Yes | Yes | Yes |
123       |      4         | 5/10/2019 | Yes | Yes | Yes |
123       |      5         | 6/28/2019 | Yes | Yes | Yes |
```

**Query Result when Min or distinct is used**

`select a.filing_id, a.Version_number, min(a.filing_date), a.hy, a.cf, a.d4 from TableA a where a.filing_id = '123' group by a.filing_id, a.Version_number,  a.hy, a.cf, a.d4`:

```
   Filing ID | Version Number | Filing Date| HY  | CF |  D4  |
    
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    123      |       1        | 1/18/2019  | Yes | Yes | No  | 
    123      |       3        | 4/1/2019   | Yes | Yes | Yes |
```

**How I would like the result set to show to gain a easier count:**

```
Filing ID | Version Number | Filing Date | HY  | CF   | D4   |

------------------------------------------------------------------------
123       |      1        | 1/18/2019   | Yes  | Yes  | Null | 
123       |      3        | 4/1/2019    | Null | Null | Yes  |
```

**Final Output after query is built**:

```
Quarter(Jan-Mar, April-June, etc.) | HY | CF | D4 |

------------------------------------------------------------------------
Quarter 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
Quarter 2 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
Quarter 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
Quarter 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
```

Do I need to use "Min" or Distinct at all or would a better idea be to create a sub-query with a "Exist/Not Exist"? Am I even approaching this type of query correctly?  My dataset it huge so I'm only giving a small set to grasp what I am trying to achieve.  Thank you to all that can assist in either my lost approach or overthinking a simple approach.

Comment: Selecting a record or calculating a value based on data in another record is tricky. Why are only versions 1 and 3 returned in the GROUP BY query? What is the frontend interface? If Access, I might resort to VBA because right off I am not seeing a query only solution.

Comment: @June7  I am working out of Aqua Data Studio. The reason why version 1 and 3 comes out is because I am placing "min" before the filing date. This gives me the correct values (giving me the first time "Yes" was noted for the column headers). Yet if you notice, it is giving me the "Yes" for the other columns. I want to find a way to eliminate showing me the "Yes" for each.  Take a look at version 3, I am getting "Yes" for the other columns because if you see in the main table each version contains the answers. If i export to excel, a VBA solution might be a route but man I am rusty in that.

Comment: I tested your query on your sample data and all version numbers are returned, not just 1 and 3.

Comment: Are Jan/Feb/Mar in same quarter? If so, then D4 first Yes is in Quarter1 not Quarter2. But you want Quarter1 to show Null because Jan and Feb were No?

Comment: I can get the output using Access DCount() domain aggregate function. I suppose a correlated subquery could replicate DCount(). No idea if it will perform faster. If you want to see what I did, let me know and I will provide answer.

Comment: @June7 Thank you for taking the time. Let me say that off hand. Next, yes you are correct, march is 1st quarter, my mistake from making sure I laid this out correct. Regardless the final tally is what I am trying to accomplish where I'm not double counting the Yes due to the versions that come along with the filing id. So in HY case though it is showing Yes for both date results, it should only be counted once cause Yes was at the earliest date and shouldn't be counted again. Same with the other columns. Thanks again. Sometimes I wish I could do real time explanations, lol.

Comment: @June7 Appreciate the offer, any suggestion is welcomed. I am scouring the sight at the same time trying to find at least something similar to this.  Even if I have to switch the approach.

Comment: @Belayer has provided an answer. Does it work for you? In Access I used Format(Filing_Date, "yyyyq") to calculate quarter for grouping.

Comment: @June7 that is damned close. Yet I explained the yes only once situation. I am going to try to tinker with it to see if I can add something and edit my post for my mistakes in explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets simplify your data a bit.

Assuming the columns `HY`, `CF` and `D4` are of the `boolean` type:

```
create table table_a(filing_date date, hi bool, cf bool, d4 bool);
insert into table_a values
    ('2019-01-18', true, true, false),
    ('2019-01-19', false, false, false), --< note this gap
    ('2019-02-10', true, true, false),
    ('2019-04-01', true, true, true),
    ('2019-05-10', true, true, true),
    ('2019-06-28', true, true, true);
```

Lets remove repeated data using special window syntax:

```
select
    filing_date,
    case when count(nullif(hi, false)) over w = 1 and hi then 1 else 0 end as hi,
    case when count(nullif(cf, false)) over w = 1 and cf then 1 else 0 end as cf,
    case when count(nullif(d4, false)) over w = 1 and d4 then 1 else 0 end as d4
from table_a
window w as (
    order by filing_date
    rows between unbounded preceding and current row);

┌─────────────┬────┬────┬────┐
│ filing_date │ hi │ cf │ d4 │
├─────────────┼────┼────┼────┤
│ 2019-01-18  │  1 │  1 │  0 │
│ 2019-01-19  │  0 │  0 │  0 │
│ 2019-02-10  │  0 │  0 │  0 │
│ 2019-04-01  │  0 │  0 │  1 │
│ 2019-05-10  │  0 │  0 │  0 │
│ 2019-06-28  │  0 │  0 │  0 │
└─────────────┴────┴────┴────┘
```

And collapse the result by quarters:

```
with t as (
    select
        filing_date,
        case when count(nullif(hi, false)) over w = 1 and hi then 1 else 0 end as hi,
        case when count(nullif(cf, false)) over w = 1 and cf then 1 else 0 end as cf,
        case when count(nullif(d4, false)) over w = 1 and d4 then 1 else 0 end as d4
    from table_a
    window w as (
        order by filing_date
        rows between unbounded preceding and current row))
select
    to_char(filing_date, 'Q') as quarter,
    sum(hi) as hi, sum(cf) as cf, sum(d4) as d4
from t group by 1 order by 1;

┌─────────┬────┬────┬────┐
│ quarter │ hi │ cf │ d4 │
├─────────┼────┼────┼────┤
│ 1       │  1 │  1 │  0 │
│ 2       │  0 │  0 │  1 │
└─────────┴────┴────┴────┘
```

Finally if you need to show empty quarters:

```
with
  t as (
    select
        filing_date,
        case when count(nullif(hi, false)) over w = 1 and hi then 1 else 0 end as hi,
        case when count(nullif(cf, false)) over w = 1 and cf then 1 else 0 end as cf,
        case when count(nullif(d4, false)) over w = 1 and d4 then 1 else 0 end as d4
    from table_a
    window w as (
        order by filing_date
        rows between unbounded preceding and current row)),
  d as (
    select
        to_char(filing_date, 'Q') as quarter,
        sum(hi) as hi, sum(cf) as cf, sum(d4) as d4
    from t group by 1 order by 1)
select
    quarter,
    coalesce(hi, 0) as hi,
    coalesce(cf, 0) as cf,
    coalesce(d4, 0) as d4
from
    (values('1'),('2'),('3'),('4')) as q(quarter) natural left join d
order by quarter;

┌─────────┬────┬────┬────┐
│ quarter │ hi │ cf │ d4 │
├─────────┼────┼────┼────┤
│ 1       │  1 │  1 │  0 │
│ 2       │  0 │  0 │  1 │
│ 3       │  0 │  0 │  0 │
│ 4       │  0 │  0 │  0 │
└─────────┴────┴────┴────┘
```

<kbd>[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=01c5cc8861c2c26813a7f3773f1b6eb2)</kbd>

PS: For the large amount of data change the initial query to

```
select
    filing_date,
    case when exists (select 1 from table_a as b where b.filing_date < a.filing_date and hi) or not hi then 0 else 1 end as hi,
    case when exists (select 1 from table_a as b where b.filing_date < a.filing_date and cf) or not cf then 0 else 1 end as cf,
    case when exists (select 1 from table_a as b where b.filing_date < a.filing_date and d4) or not d4 then 0 else 1 end as d4
from table_a as a;
```

There are several SQL goodies rarely used:

- `window` clause that allows to define the range for several window aggregates without repeating it
- `count(nullif())` - when parameter specified this aggregation counting only non null values. In pseudocode `count(null, 'a', null)` returns 1, not 3
- `natural join` - joins two tables by column names for example if both `t1` and `t2` tables have columns `a` and `b` then `t1 natural join t2` is same to `t1 join t2 on t1.a=ty2.a and t1.b=t2.b`

Comment: this is the one.  Just one question. I have more filing ids to go with those columns (hy, cf, d4).  The section where you show the window syntax is EXACTLY the layout I need and results but when I open up the range (meaning more than one filing id with multiple versions, I am not getting the correct answers for the columns. So do I add an additional parameter to the window syntax, like "order by filing_id, sbmtd_dt"?  Thank you very very much indeed..

Comment: @ACKoop It is simplified example that shows the direction. Any additional columns, filters, grouping and ordering is depending on your actual schema/data. Answering to your question: add `partition by` clause to the window definition.

Answer (score 0):

You can count each occurrence of 'Yes' for the columns, then use the least function to reduce and count over 1 to 1.  There is no reason to go through your intermediate result set. I could not reproduce you stated results exactly as you did not provide the magic formula for determining quarter, but it's close. See [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f09d713c576f9337a6978d846b8b9e88).

```
with quarters(quarter,date_range) as 
     ( values (1, daterange(date '2019-01-01',date '2019-03-01'),'[)')
            , (2, daterange(date '2019-03-01',date '2019-07-01'),'[)')
            , (3, daterange(date '2019-07-01',date '2019-10-01'),'[)') 
            , (4, daterange(date '2019-10-01',date '2020-01-01'),'[)')
     )
select 'Quarter' || to_char(quarter,'99') quarter
     , least(hy,1) hy 
     , least(cf,1) cf
     , least(d4,1) d4
  from ( 
         select quarter  
              , count(1) filter (where hy = 'Yes') hy
              , count(1) filter (where cf = 'Yes') cf 
              , count(1) filter (where d4 = 'Yes') d4
           from tablea
           right join quarters on filing_date <@ date_range 
           group by quarter  
       ) q
 order by quarter;
```

Comment: I feel this is on track. The thing is I am not trying to count each Yes on each version. So HY should only have Yes in the first quarter and never again. So its a count once in the quarterly date range and it doesn't get a count again unless a new value is present in a "No" column (D4).  I am going to edit the final chart since it was my mistake on the 'quarter' ranged as pointed out by June7.  Please give me a moment to tinker with this though and see.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
SELECT Filing_ID, YrQtr, Max(H1) AS HF, Max(C1) AS CF, Max(D1) AS D4
FROM (SELECT TableA.*, Format([Filing_Date],"yyyyq") AS YrQtr, 
         (SELECT Count("*") FROM TableA AS Dup 
          WHERE Filing_ID=TableA.Filing_ID 
                 AND HY=True AND Year(Filing_Date)=Year(TableA.Filing_Date) 
                 AND Version_Number<TableA.Version_Number) AS H,
         (SELECT Count("*") FROM TableA AS Dup 
          WHERE Filing_ID=TableA.Filing_ID 
                 AND CF=True AND Year(Filing_Date)=Year(TableA.Filing_Date) 
                 AND Version_Number<TableA.Version_Number) AS C, 
         (SELECT Count("*") FROM TableA AS Dup 
          WHERE Filing_ID=TableA.Filing_ID 
                 AND D4=True AND Year(Filing_Date)=Year(TableA.Filing_Date)
                 AND Version_Number<TableA.Version_Number) AS D, 
         IIf([HY]=True And [H]=0,1,0) AS H1, 
         IIf([CF]=True And [C]=0,1,0) AS C1, 
         IIf([D4]=True And [D]=0,1,0) AS D1 
      FROM TableA) AS Query1
GROUP BY Filing_ID, YrQtr;
```